# Determine the filesize of iOS App before submitting to App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Apps larger than 20MB in size will not download over cellular networks ([App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)).

How can I test the filesize of my App before submitting? After creating the Archive in Xcode, if I go to "Share..." there are options for creating an "iOS App Store Package (.ipa)" and "Archive", but these result in somewhat different file sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ipa is the thing that you have to look at. The archive conains debugging information and so that is not uploaded to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

In the organizer, share the app for (ad hoc) distribution via iTunes (not archives). 
Then, in iTunes, you can locate the app binary and see the size in Finder.